# Wordpress - Automatically add author name in post title for a certain category

Tags: wordpress

I would like to add the author name of my post automatically in the post title when i click on "Publish".

I try this code but it did not work :

```
add_action( 'wp_insert_post_data', 'obm_set_category_title', 99 );

function obm_set_category_title( $data, $postarr ) {

    if ( 'mycategoryname' == $postarr['post_category'] ) {

        $title = $data['post_author'] . ' : ' . $data['post_title'];
        $data['post_title'] = $title;
    }

    return $data;

}

?>
```

Any advice ? Thanks by advance :) !

Comment: For all post type or specific post type.??

Comment: For all post in a specific category

Answer (score 0):

Jonathon,
use a filter instead, actions allow you to DO something, but do expect data to be returned - they do not do anything with that data.

FILTERS allow you to affect the data that is being worked, so are a better choice. Maybe this filter:   https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/wp_insert_post_data.

Personally I suggest that rather than embedding the author name in the title in the DB, you could rather add it at display time.  eg again using a filter but this time perhaps this one? https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/the_title

Comment: I tried the filter but without result. I don't know how to properly get the author name in the function.

Answer (score 0):

Try This.

```
        function fun_update_post_title( $post_id, $post, $update  ) {
     //Get category by post id and put condition

        // If this is just a revision
        if ( wp_is_post_revision( $post_id ) )
            return;

        $post_author_name = get_the_author_meta( "display_name",$post->post_author );
        $post_title = $post_author_name."::".$post->post_title;

        $my_post = array(
          'ID'           => $post_id,
          'post_title'   => $post_title
      );




        // unhook this function so it doesn't loop infinitely
        remove_action('save_post', 'fun_update_post_title');
        // update the post, which calls save_post again
        wp_update_post( $my_post );
        // re-hook this function
        add_action('save_post', 'fun_update_post_title');
    }

   //call function whene post in save 
   add_action( 'save_post', 'fun_update_post_title', 10, 3 );
```

Comment: if specific post type (CPT) then use save_post_{post_type_slug} action hook.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, did I have to put all this code in functions.php ? Because at the moment I have a white page when I try to go to "Add post".

Comment: I have 2 error : Warning: Missing argument 2 for fun_update_post_title() and Warning: Missing argument 3 for fun_update_post_title(). Did you know how can I fix them ? Sorry im bad on php

Comment: Thanks for your update, I don't have any errors now but when I want to create a new post it does a 404 error :/

Comment: code updated.please add this code in your active theme function.php file.